# updating a line object via a function in 3D matplotlib

Tags: widget, interactive, matplotlib-3d

I would like to use a widget to plot the y-trace of a 3d function.
I 2D everything goes well, the update function update the y values of the 2D line object.

But in 3D , noting happens, I set the y values and change them with the slider but the line does not move. Im' quite confused.

Here are the two version of the code
in 2D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
fig=plt.figure()

ax1=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,0.8])
x=np.linspace(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,300)
y=np.sin(x)
drawing,=plt.plot(x,y)


def update(val):
    freq=s_x.val
    y=np.sin(freq*x)
    drawing.set_ydata(y)
    plt.draw()


slider_position=plt.axes([0.25,0.03,0.4,0.04])

s_x=Slider(slider_position, 'fréquence',1,6,valinit=2)
s_x.on_changed(update)
update(1)

plt.show()
```

And in 3D

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


fig_1=plt.figure(figsize=[7,4])
ax1=fig_1.add_subplot(projection='3d') 




slider_position=plt.axes([0.25,0.03,0.4,0.04])

s_y=Slider(slider_position,'trace of y',-5,5,valinit=0)

x_point=np.linspace(-5,5,25)
y_point=np.full(25,2)
z_trace_y=x_point**2+y_point
trace_y,=ax1.plot(x_point,y_point,z_trace_y,'r')


def update(val):
    
    test=s_y.val
    
    y_point=np.full(25,test)
    trace_y.set_ydata(y_point)
    plt.draw()
    
      

s_y.on_changed(update)  


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `projection='3d'` to create a subplot, your update function must re-assign values to all 3 dimensions. Without this, the line will not move or may even disappear completely!

#### Solution

Use `trace_y.set_data(...)` to change the `x` and `y` data points. Then use `trace_y.set_3d_properties(...)` to update the data points on the `z-axis`. Do all of this within your update function.

#### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

fig_1=plt.figure(figsize=[7,4])
ax1=fig_1.add_subplot(projection='3d') 

ax1.set_ylim(-6,6) # THIS HELPS KEEP YOUR LINE WITHIN VIEW

slider_position=plt.axes([0.25,0.03,0.4,0.04])

s_y=Slider(slider_position,'trace of y',-5,5,valinit=0)

x_point=np.linspace(-5,5,25)
y_point=np.full(25,2)
z_trace_y=x_point**2+y_point
trace_y,=ax1.plot(x_point,y_point,z_trace_y,'r')

def update(val):
    test=s_y.val
    
    y_point=np.full(25,test)
    z_trace_y=x_point**2+y_point # RE-CALCULATE Z
    trace_y.set_data(x_point,y_point) # SET VALUES FOR X/Y
    trace_y.set_3d_properties(z_trace_y) # SET Z-VALUES
    plt.draw()

s_y.on_changed(update)  

plt.show()
```